# React-Native and xcode 10 - Set Base SDK to 12.1 but compiles to 11

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I can't update my app on the app store because it won't compile with SDK version 12.1.

Everytime I try to upload my app I get this message:

`SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 11.2 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK or later, included in Xcode 9 or later. Further, starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later.`

In my project settings `Base SDK` is set to `ios 12.1`

After reading other issues like this, I have also deleted xcode 9 from my computer. But still nothing is working.

Any idea what is forcing my app to compile with 11.2?

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling xcode 9, I had to re-install xcode 10.